# Как защитить бота на heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, бот

У меня есть вк-бот, развернутый на heroku. Написан на python3 и использует библиотеку vk_api.
Проблема в том, что к любому приложению на heroku можно отправить HTTP-запрос по адресу *<имя приложения>*.herokuapp.com.

Если отправить подобный запрос моему стабильно работающему боту, то он падает с таким сообщением:

> at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/"
> host=botidiot.herokuapp.com
> request_id=8126ad22-e2a2-4ae1-9d3b-5e1fe6205e28 fwd="37.113.168.51"
> dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http

Из сообщения понятно, что нет запущенных процессов типа `web`, способных обработать запрос (естественно, я использую единственный процесс типа worker).

Получается, любой, кто перейдет по адресу *<имя приложения>.herokuapp.com*, может остановить работу моего бота. Мне это не нравится. Как защититься от подобного рода воздействий без использования Django, Flask и т.п., способных обработать запрос?

Comment: Принимать какой-нибудь ключ в GET запросе, например, но я не эксперт

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я провёл 3 часа в поиске решения данной проблемы.
Нашёл только один выход, и то, костыль, но бот падать не будет.

Heroku не любит, когда пользователи деплоят не веб-приложения, при каждом деплое оно хочет видеть запущенный веб-сервер.

Итак, перейдём к решению.

Мы создадим файл с сервером на flask, чтобы Heroku обрабатывало запрос и скрипты не падали.

В корневой директории создаём файл **f.py**:

```
import os
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return ""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

В `requirements.txt` дописываем `flask`

В `Procfile` дописываем строчку `web: python f.py`

Редеплоим, запускаем Dyno через панель управления приложением. Done.